# Objective C - Detect a "path" drawing, inside a map image

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, path, core-graphics, image-recognition

I have a physical map (real world), for example, a little town map.
A "path" line is painted over the map, think about it like "you are here. here's how to reach the train station" :)
Now, let's suppose I can get an image of that scenario (likewise, coming from a photo).
An image that looks like:

[image: Map path example]

My goal is not easy way out!

I want to **GET the path OUT of the image, i.e., separate the two layers.**

Is there a way to extract those red marks from the image?

Maybe using CoreGraphics? Maybe an external library?
It's not an objective C specific question, but I am working on Apple iOS.

I already worked with something similar, the face-recognition.
Now the answer I expect is: "What do you mean by PATH?" 
Well, I really don't know, maybe a line (see above image) of a completely different color from the 'major' colors in the background.
Let's talk about it.

Comment: Where are you getting the image from? Google Maps/MapKit, or is it user-supplied? Can you get the map without the path?

Comment: The map is a _real_ map! The picture is coming from a photo of the real map. I can't get it without the path, the path is simply a painting.

Comment: So, user-supplied. Are they all from the same source? Can you provide an actual example?

Comment: No! And that's the difficult part: map can be every kind of real map with a path painting.

Comment: do try and post the outputs you get from the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use OpenCV then it becomes simpler. Here's a general method:

1. Separate the image into Hue, Saturation and Variation (HSV colorspace)

   Here's the OpenCV code:

   // Compute HSV image and separate into colors
   IplImage* hsv = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );

   cvCvtColor( img, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV );

   IplImage* h_plane = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize( img ), 8, 1 );

   IplImage* s_plane = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize( img ), 8, 1 );

   IplImage* v_plane = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize( img ), 8, 1 );

   cvCvtPixToPlane( hsv, h_plane, s_plane, v_plane, 0 );
2. Deal with the Hue (h_plane) image only as it gives just the hue without any change in value for a lighter or darker shade of the same color
3. Check which pixels have Red hue (i think red is 0 degree for HSV, but please check the OpenCV values)
4. Copy these pixels into a separate image

I's strongly suggest using the OpenCV library if possible, which is basically made for such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the color, define a threshold for what the color red is, then filter everything else to alpha, and you have left over what your "path" is?

Comment: Can you give me more details on how to do that, please?